# How to derive a website absolute file path from a WCF service hosted in IIS?

Tags: wcf

How can one determine the absolute filepath of the WCF service root folder that's hosted in IIS?

I've investigated `System.ServiceModel.OperationContext` and discovered various relative URI paths, but no absolute paths that contain the service root folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little digging around the .NET framework I discovered:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
```

This gets the physical path on disk to the application's directory, i.e. in the case of a WCF service hosted from IIS, the virtual folder's absolute file path.